# Noob question about an exponential congruence

Tags: modular-arithmetic, modules, congruences, congruence-relations

When is this congruence true for integer $a>1$?

$$(a-1)^{(a+1)} \equiv (a-1) \> mod \> (a^2-1)$$

My try:

$$(a-1)^{a} \equiv \> 1 \> mod \>  (a+1)(a-1)$$

I do not know what to do now.

Thank you.

Comment: It's not true for a = 3, because $2^4 \equiv 0 \not \equiv 2 \mod 8$.

Comment: Since $a-1$ divides the modulus, you have to divide that as well. So you end up with $(a-1)^a \equiv 1 \pmod{(a + 1)}$, which is false for $a=3$.

Comment: @quasi one can show that this is true exactly for $a = p - 1$, where $p$ is prime.

Comment: @Santiago -- I'm on my way out -- I'll look at this later.

Comment: Thank you! Then, do I have to use Fernat's Theorem?